# Is it possible to create a string in C# and use it with PowerShell?

Tags: c#, powershell

Is it possible to create a string in a C# .exe and use this string in PowerShell?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Your question is quite vague - are you using a powershell script to create an object from the c# assembly, then using that object?  If so, simply set a property to the string you want and access it as normal from powershell.

Or, if it's a static method, you can just call it

```
   [My.Assembly.Type]::GetSomeString()
```

If you are running the c# exe, you can simply output it with writeline and powershell will pick it up:

```
.\myexe.exe > $someVar
```

Or, you can [write it as a cmdlet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/daiken/archive/2007/02/07/creating-a-windows-powershell-cmdlet-using-the-visual-studio-windows-powershell-templates.aspx), and your c# code can participate in the pipeline.

Comment: This is the only answer that is related to "C# .exe" :) Voted up. The others are obviously missing that.

Answer (score 4):

In the event you are hosting PowerShell within a C# app and you want to access a string variable defined in C# from the PowerShell script that you run, here's how to do that:

```
string foo = "some string defined in C# to be used in PowerShell";
runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("foo", foo);
```

You can then reference this variable in your PowerShell script as `$foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use .NET classes in powershell, for instance you can use:

```
PS C:\> [System.Environment]::GetLogicalDrives()
```

when dealing with a static method.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell uses the .net Framework under the covers, all objects are CLR object